# How long does a player stay in the ICC rankings for once no longer appearing for the national side?

Tags: cricket, icc, ranking

Batsmen and bowlers have an individual rating between 0-1000 based on performances, and naturally their ratings drop for each game missed.

Is their a specific time period after which their rating disappears completely?

I remember Brett Schultz being on the old PWC rankings for at least two years after his last appearance for South Africa, and Kevin Pietersen is England's third highest batsman 18 months after playing his last test.

Answer (score 2):

The [ICC Rankings FAQ](http://www.icc-cricket.com/player-rankings/faqs) notes that

> Players have to have appeared in a match within the qualifying period to appear in the lists (normally 12-15 months for Tests [...])

As such, Pietersen would not "normally" count as qualified for the rankings. I don't know if this is because he's being treated as a special case due to his... unique relationship with the England cricket team, or just because it hasn't been removed yet and that will happen sometime this summer.